# Infinite Series Limiting Value

Tags: sequences-and-series

**EDIT:**

> Find the converging value of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{(n-1) \lambda^n}{n!}$.

I just know that

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$ for all x.

So I can split up the summation into 2 terms:

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}  \cfrac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!} -\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda^n}{n!}$

**Term 1:**

Perform variable substitution setting $(n-1)=k \implies n=k+1$

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}  \cfrac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!}
= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda^{k+1}}{k!}
= \lambda \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}
= \lambda (e^{\lambda}+1)$

**Term 2**

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda^n}{n!}=e^{\lambda}-1- \lambda$

Now we combine both terms getting:

$\lambda (e^{\lambda}+1) -e^{\lambda}+1+ \lambda$

I'm getting a different answer than below, but I still don't think this is right.  Can someone please verify?

Thank you.

Comment: Split it, $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n\lambda^n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$. That the sum doesn't start at $0$ just means you have to subtract a few terms from the exponential.

Comment: Do you want to sum the series?

Comment: I'm looking for the limit.  What is the sum yes... @MhenniBenghorbal

Comment: $\lambda^n=\lambda\cdot\lambda^{n-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just make that an answer! Else we end up with unawnsered questions! Also, it has happened already that I answer and you have given the exact same hint/answer in the comments, and I feel bad =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff In this case, I think we can leave it at the existing answer. In general, I feel bad solving what I believe to be other people's homework problems completely, and I don't particularly like posting incomplete answers. Concerning your feeling bad: don't. Feel good when that happens, great minds think alike and all that ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I agree with Peter.  Questions are meant to be answered.  Answering in the comments does kind of spoil the experience.

Comment: I don't care if it is homework or not, I just think question must be answered =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I edited question.  Can you please verify?  I don't think MhenniBenghorbal is correct.

Comment: @user1527227 I gave you an answer. You had a sign wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{(n - 1){\lambda ^n}}}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{{\lambda ^n}}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{{\lambda ^n}}}{{n!}}} $$

And further $$\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{{\lambda ^n}}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  = \lambda \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\lambda ^n}}}{{n!}}}  = \lambda \left( {{e^\lambda } - 1} \right)$$ while $$\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{{\lambda ^n}}}{{n!}}}  = {e^\lambda } - 1 - \lambda $$

Comment: @user1527227 Any time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{(n-1) \lambda^n}{n!} =\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{n \lambda^n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{ \lambda^n}{n!}
= \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \cfrac{ \lambda^n}{(n-1)!}-(e^x-1-x) $$

$$ = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{ \lambda^{n+1}}{n!}-(e^{\lambda}-1-\lambda)  $$

$$ =\lambda\left( e^{\lambda}-1 \right)-( e^{\lambda}-1-\lambda ). $$

Comment: Doesn't ratio test just tell you whether it converges or diverges?  I am looking for the sum.

Comment: @user1527227: See the edit.

Comment: Thanks @MhenniBenghorba! Did you do variable substitution on your summation for line 2?  If so let's say $k=(n-1)$, then if n starts at 2, k=1.  Should your starting limit on the second line be 1?

Comment: What is $x$?....

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution.

Comment: Mhenni: you're introducing a variable $x$; when it should be $\lambda$!

Comment: And the last way you change the variable sum is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @user1527227: It is $\lambda$ not $x$. It is a typo.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: It is a small mistake. I was in hurry when I solved the problem.

Comment: @user1527227: The method is correct.